# change a css-rule of a class with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a weird problem and yet no solution was found. I am in need of changing a css-rule (say border-color) of a class with javaScript.

Let's think  I have a bunch of div like this:

```css
.patient{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  height:30px;
  margin:5px
}
.patient.active{
  border-color : red;
}
```

```html
<div class="patient active"></div>
<div class="patient"></div>
<div class="patient"></div>
<div class="patient"></div>
<div class="patient"></div>
```

Now, the user should be able to change '.active' border-color in a way that whenever each div becomes active, it takes the new value as if I have changed the css rule in css file. When I set the border-color , it is added like a inline style to the selected div

Comment: It's not a duplicate of mentioned above answer, but i think is incorrect question. Amir probably ask about the whole logic of making element `.active`

Comment: *change a css-rule of a class with javascript*?  You can override it instead.  Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you please be more explanatory?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model

Comment: More coded added guys, unfortunately the more I search the less I find!!